# How can I get an extra value to print during a particular time in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-c++, accumulator, accumulate

I am having trouble figuring out how to add an extra place to print a value after a particular iteration in a for loop. The program I am making is a simple employee wage calculator for practice. I use a for loop to gather the daily input for hours and do calculations in a nested for loop. When I try to print out the weekly total(or however many days) for a particular employee, the variable doesn't clear out. So I basically get a grand total, not a total printed at the end of that employee.

The output right now looks like what is below this and the code is below that.

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Employee Wage Tracker

Enter the Number of Employees: 3
Enter the Number of Days Worked: 3

Enter the hourly rate for employee(1): $10

Enter the hours worked for each of the following days
EmployeeNumber(1)/DayNumber(1)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(1)/DayNumber(2)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(1)/DayNumber(3)-Hours Worked: 10
Grand Total: $300

Enter the hourly rate for employee(2): $20

Enter the hours worked for each of the following days
EmployeeNumber(2)/DayNumber(1)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(2)/DayNumber(2)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(2)/DayNumber(3)-Hours Worked: 10
Grand Total: $900

Enter the hourly rate for employee(3): $15

Enter the hours worked for each of the following days
EmployeeNumber(3)/DayNumber(1)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(3)/DayNumber(2)-Hours Worked: 10
EmployeeNumber(3)/DayNumber(3)-Hours Worked: 10
Grand Total: $1350
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

I want to print out each employee's total wages individually, without adding each employee into a grand total. I want to call it something like "Employee Weekly Total".

```
//Employee Wage Tracker
#include <iostream>


// Variables

int counterEmployee = 0;
int counterDays = 0; 

int getValueFromUserPart1() {

    //Collect users initial input for number of employees and amount of days worked
    std::cout << "Employee Wage Tracker";
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter the Number of Employees: ";
    int employeeTotal = 0;
    std::cin >> employeeTotal;

    //catch user if zero or negative employees entered
    while (employeeTotal <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Amount of Employees: ";
        std::cin >> employeeTotal;

        return employeeTotal;
    }
    return employeeTotal;
}

int getValueFromUserPart2() {

    std::cout << "Enter the Number of Days Worked: ";
    int daysWorked = 0;
    std::cin >> daysWorked;

    //catch user if zero or negative days worked entered
    while (daysWorked <= 0) {
        std::cout << "\nPlease Enter a Positive Number for Days: ";
        std::cin >> daysWorked;

        return daysWorked;
    }
    return daysWorked;
}
double ratesForWages() {

    //employee wage information
    std::cout << "\nEnter the hourly rate for employee(" << counterEmployee + 1 << "): $";

    double wageRate; //hold wage rate for this employee
    std::cin >> wageRate; //hold wage rate for this employee


    //catch user to make sure wage rate is positive
    while (wageRate < 0) {
        std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Wage for Employee(" << counterEmployee + 1 << "): $";
        std::cin >> wageRate;

        return wageRate;
    }
    return wageRate;
}


int main() {

    int employeeTotal{ getValueFromUserPart1() };
    int daysWorked{ getValueFromUserPart2() };

    double grandTotal{};

    //Loop to count the number of employees and loop to count days worked
    for (counterEmployee = 0; counterEmployee < employeeTotal; ++counterEmployee) {

        double wageRate{ ratesForWages() };

        std::cout << "\nEnter the hours worked for each of the following days\n";

        for (int counterDays = 0; counterDays < daysWorked; ++counterDays) {

            //variables for day loops
            double hours{};  //holds hours worked for that day
            double dailyTotal{}; //holds daily total earnings

            std::cout << "EmployeeNumber(" << counterEmployee + 1 << ")/";
            std::cout << "DayNumber(" << counterDays + 1 << ")-" << "Hours Worked: ";
            std::cin >> hours;

            //catch user to make sure hours worked is not negative
            while (hours < 0) {
                std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Amount of Hours: ";
                std::cin >> hours;
            }
                //calculate daily total earnings and add it to the overall total
                dailyTotal = hours * wageRate;
                grandTotal += dailyTotal;

        } 


        //std::cout << "Current Total for Employee: " << "$" << currentTotal << "\n";
        std::cout << "Grand Total: " << "$" << grandTotal << "\n";

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I recommend that you try to use a more descriptive name than `getValueFromUserPart1` or `getValueFromUserPart2`. As for your problem, you need to store the data for each employee separately. Like in an array of employee *objects* from which you can get the data needed and sum it up as you need.

Comment: You return inside the `while` loop of `getValueFromUserPart1` and other functions, while you actually want to keep asking till you're sure that the input is correct. That return can be removed already. If it's intended as one test only, make it an `if` test.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly went through your code, and I think what you mean is that the `grandTotal` shouldn't contain the hours of other employees. To do this, all you have to do is making sure that the value will be reset after each iteration. In this case it was sufficient to move the declaration inside the `for`-loop.

Also, I de-commented some of the returns, since you probably don't want to have them, and suggested new names for your functions, so they're a bit more self-documenting and you can easily understand them, without having to remember what they do.

As Programmer Dude mentioned; C++ is an object based programming language. The way you're using it is rather an imperative approach, but I guess you're just getting the hang of C++ syntax, before diving into classes.

The code:

```cpp
//Employee Wage Tracker
#include <iostream>


// Variables

int counterEmployee = 0;
int counterDays = 0;

int getEmployeeNumber() {

    //Collect users initial input for number of employees and amount of days worked
    std::cout << "Employee Wage Tracker";
    std::cout << "\n\nEnter the Number of Employees: ";
    int employeeTotal = 0;
    std::cin >> employeeTotal;

    //catch user if zero or negative employees entered
    while (employeeTotal <= 0) {
        std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Amount of Employees: ";
        std::cin >> employeeTotal;

        // return employeeTotal; don't return because you're not sure the input is correct yet!
    }
    return employeeTotal;
}

int getWorkDaysNumber() {

    std::cout << "Enter the Number of Days Worked: ";
    int daysWorked = 0;
    std::cin >> daysWorked;

    //catch user if zero or negative days worked entered
    while (daysWorked <= 0) {
        std::cout << "\nPlease Enter a Positive Number for Days: ";
        std::cin >> daysWorked;

        // return daysWorked;
    }
    return daysWorked;
}
double getHourlyRateNumber() {

    //employee wage information
    std::cout << "\nEnter the hourly rate for employee(" << counterEmployee + 1 << "): $";

    double wageRate; //hold wage rate for this employee
    std::cin >> wageRate; //hold wage rate for this employee


    //catch user to make sure wage rate is positive
    while (wageRate < 0) {
        std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Wage for Employee(" << counterEmployee + 1 << "): $";
        std::cin >> wageRate;

        // return wageRate;
    }
    return wageRate;
}


int main() {

    int employeeTotal{ getEmployeeNumber() };
    int daysWorked{ getWorkDaysNumber() };


    //Loop to count the number of employees and loop to count days worked
    for (counterEmployee = 0; counterEmployee < employeeTotal; ++counterEmployee) {

        double grandTotal{};
        double wageRate{ getHourlyRateNumber() };

        std::cout << "\nEnter the hours worked for each of the following days\n";

        for (int counterDays = 0; counterDays < daysWorked; ++counterDays) {

            //variables for day loops
            double hours{};  //holds hours worked for that day
            double dailyTotal{}; //holds daily total earnings

            std::cout << "EmployeeNumber(" << counterEmployee + 1 << ")/";
            std::cout << "DayNumber(" << counterDays + 1 << ")-" << "Hours Worked: ";
            std::cin >> hours;

            //catch user to make sure hours worked is not negative
            while (hours < 0) {
                std::cout << "Please Enter a Positive Amount of Hours: ";
                std::cin >> hours;
            }
            //calculate daily total earnings and add it to the overall total
            dailyTotal = hours * wageRate;
            grandTotal += dailyTotal;

        }


        //std::cout << "Current Total for Employee: " << "$" << currentTotal << "\n";
        std::cout << "Grand Total: " << "$" << grandTotal << "\n";

    }
}
```